# Twilio Bulk SMS API in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, twilio

Do we have bulk SMS Api code in salesforce available? i have not found in twilio document.please guide on the same.

I have search in twilio document and google it but not found expected result for the same.
is there any related post or code share or document provide for bulk messaging through salesforce?.